# Find nth Fibonacci Number, using iteration and recursion

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, comparative-review, c++14

I'm a beginner programmer and I came upon this problem which is to find the *n*​th number in the Fibonacci series.

I used to solve the problem using a `for` loop; today I learned about recursion but there is a problem: when I pass 40 or 41 to the recursive function, it takes a bit of time to calculate it, while in the iterative method it would instantly give me the answers.

I have these questions:

1. Why do most people (on the Internet) recommend using recursion?   Because it's simpler and easier to write the program?  (Logically I thought that we should write it in a way that is fast and simple)
2. Here are the 2 methods that a beginner like me can handle writing at the moment.  Is there a better way than these two methods?  And are these methods complex?

Here is the recursive method:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long n);

    unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long n){
        if(n<=1)
            return n;                                //base case
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);      //recursive case
    }

    int main(){
        unsigned int a {};
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << fibonacci(a) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

And here is the iterative (looping) method:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n{};
    unsigned long long t1{0}, t2{1};
    unsigned long long sum{};
    cout << "Enter the number of terms: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Fibonacci Series: ";
    for (int i{2}; i < n; ++i) {
        sum = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = sum;
    }
    cout << t2;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I know that `using namespace std` is a bad idea but I have also tried the same thing without the namespace and still I get the delay, so I did it here because it's easy to understand.

---

Edit1: First of all I would like to thank everyone who commented and answered my question...To be honest I didn't think that this question would bring a lot of attention to the community so I appreciate the time you put on this and it means a lot to me.

Edit2: Let me demonstrate some of the things that might have been a little odd to you.

Q: What do you mean by better when you say if there is a better way than these two methods?
A: By better, I meant that the code shall be **simple** and also takes **less time** to execute or perform the calculations

Q: What do you mean when you say most people (on the internet) use recursion?
A: I've seen code out there that uses recursion to solve problems.  The two common problems I've seen are **Fibonacci** and **Factorial of a number**. For factorial, I have also tried both methods (iteration and recursion) but I didn't get a delay for both of them when I type large numbers like 40 or 50. The common problem I saw with recursion is that eventually, you may run out of memory space because it is calling itself multiple times which results in a stack overflow (because stack as a part of memory will be filled). Although this problem doesn't occur in this example. So this raises another question here:

**When should we use recursion?**

Comment: For most reviewers on the site, it is easier to understand if you done have the `using namespace std;` statement.

Comment: The recursive version is trivial to see you have done it correctly. The iterative version takes a bit of thought (not much but some). But you have stopped on the iterative version as if that is the correct answer. There is so much more to do. This is why I like this as an interview question (as a proxy for thinking as fib() solutions are obvious). But you can make candidates think about all the other issues.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` is not about speed. It is about maintainability. It is a bad habit that in the long run will make your code hard to maintain (and cause bugs (see linked article). That is why it is considered bad practice. [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

Comment: "*Iteration or recursion*" -- neither, there's a [closed form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)

Comment: What @canton7 says. I sometimes use this as to kick off an wide-ranging interview discussion. Present the candidate with a recursive version, get them to explain what it does, then off you go into discussions of "good/bad" metrics, performance, iterative version, look-up tables, and eventually the fact that there's a closed form (the best, even if they don't know about that, on seeing that it's about fibonnacci, quickly ask if they can google it and come up with the closed form). With C++ there's also a compile-time solution as you can do it with templates.

Comment: Congratulations on your first nice question badge. As an experiment, you might want to try putting both of these algorithms into the same main and time each function call and report back the elapsed time.

Comment: Note: It is possible find any fibonacci number in O(log n) time, or, in some cases, O(1) time.

Comment: @canton7: The closed form solution will be wrong starting at Fib(70), presuming binary64 doubles are used. The iterative solution will give a correct answer with 64-bit integer arithmetic up to Fib(92) inclusive.

Comment: *Do* 'most people (on the internet) recommend using recursion'? Really? I doubt this is true. Evidence please.

Comment: I'm completely not seeing the explanation of why the recursive method is slow in the answers: the reason is that it pretty much builds the Fibonacci number by adding lots of ones together (and therefore will add an exponentially growing number of them)

Comment: @user207421 I dont know if these count as evidence but here they are: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) and this one [link](https://www.programming9.com/programs/c-programs/339-c-program-to-find-nth-fibonacci-number-using-recursion)

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk The closed form solution can work for much larger values by using a multiprecision math library like https://gmplib.org/

Comment: "Why do most people (on the internet) recommend using recursion" - It depends on the purpose. Take the case of merge sort. For educational purposes, recursive top down merge sort is the most popular, but almost all stable sorts as implemented in libraries use some variation of a hybrid insertion sort and bottom up merge sort, such as [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Also I don't like calling it _the_ recursive version. You can write a recursive version of `fib` that's pretty fast (as in, fast enough that stack space / number range limits are going to become an issue long before performance will) (although it'll still be a _bit_ slower than the iterative version unless your compiler is doing tail call elimination).

Comment: @DavidConrad: Of course, but then that isn't an apples-to-apples comparison. If we go to multiprecision then we compare this to the O(log(n))-multiplies algorithm for computing exact integer Fibonacci number, and that would again be apples-to-apples.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Why do most people (on the internet) recommend using recursion because it's simpler and easier to write the program? Logically I thought that we should write it in a way that is fast and simple.

This is a perceptive question.  I wrote an article about exactly this topic in 2004, which you can read here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/how-not-to-teach-recursion

Summing up: there are *two* good reasons to teach people to use recursion to solve Fib:

- First, because it clearly illustrates what you have learned today. **A naive translation of a recursive definition into a recursive function can often lead to poor performance**.  That's an important lesson for beginners to take away. (EXERCISE: How many *additions* does your naive recursive program execute for a given n? The answer may surprise you.)
- Second, because the first lesson then gives us an opportunity to lead the beginner to learn **how to write a recursive algorithm so that it performs well**.

Unfortunately, as you have discovered, a great many people on the internet have not internalized that **teaching recursion via fib is solely useful as an illustration of bad uses of recursion and how to fix them**, and not in itself an example of a good use of recursion.

It would be much better if people attempting to teach recursion did so by providing a mix of good and bad recursive algorithms, and taught how to spot and avoid the bad ones.

> Is there a better way than these two methods?

Another lesson you'll quickly learn is that asking "which is better?" is a sure way to get back the reply: "can you describe a clear metric for betterness?"

So: *can you describe a clear metric for betterness?*

If the goal is to print out the nth fib number, you can do way "better" than either of your solutions:

```
unsigned long long fibs[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... }
if (0 <= n && n < sizeof(fibs... blah blah blah))
   cout << fibs[n];
```

Done. There are only so many fib numbers that fit into a long. You can look them up on the internet, copy them into your program, and you've got a short, fast fib program with no loops at all.  That's "better" to me.

But remember, the point of this exercise is to teach you something about recursion, so by that metric my program is certainly not "better".

> are these methods complex?

By "these methods" I think you mean "methods of writing recursively-stated algorithms into code other than naive recursion and unrolling the recursion into a loop".

That's a matter of opinion. Let me put it this way.

I work on a compiler team, and I interview a lot of people. My standard coding question involves writing a simple recursive algorithm on binary trees that is inefficient when written the naive way, but can be made efficient by making a few simple refactorings.  If the candidate is unable to write that clear, straightforward, efficient code, that's an easy no-hire.

Where things get interesting is when I ask "suppose you had to remove the left-hand recursion from this tree traversal; how might you do it?"

There are standard techniques for removing recursions.  Dynamic programming reduces recursions. You could make an explicit stack and use a loop.   You could make the whole algorithm tail recursive and use a language that supports tailcalls. You could use a language with cocalls. You could use continuation passing style and build a "trampoline" execution loop.

Some of these techniques are, from the perspective of the novice, terribly complicated.  I ask the question because I want to know what is in the developer's toolbox.

Comment: I also like this as an interview question. Not because of the code (as everybody can write the recursive version and anybody that has looked at any coding test has seen the iterative version). But because it leads into lots of discussions about techniques. Love the article.

Comment: "are these methods complex" - there are iterative algorithms specific to Fibonacci unrelated to optimizing recursion, one involves raising a matrix to a power, the other involves a Lucas sequence. I think this is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer...I would also like to add this to your answer...Let's say this in a very beginner friendly way...a memory has four main parts: heap(free store), stack, static variables & code area...let's talk about stack here in this fibonacci example...what I find or consider a problem with recursion is that every time the function is called, it's gonna stack the functions together sort of like calling itself multiple times...eventually you may run out of memory space...and I'm not sure but I think the term "stack overflow" is called for this solution

Comment: @DavidPeterson: That's right; in many operating systems, particularly Windows, you only get a fixed amount of stack space and by default, the activation frames for method calls go on the stack. That implies that unbounded or very deep recursions will "blow the stack". One reason for knowing about the techniques I discussed for removing recursions is to prevent stack overflows.

Comment: @DavidPeterson: A concept you might want to study is that of *continuation*. The *continuation* of a particular piece of code is *the thing that will happen when this code is done*. The stack is how we reify continuation in "normal" function calls: you call a function, and what happens next? Either the function throws, in which case the continuation is the exception handler, or it never returns normally, or it does return normally; the "normal return" continuation information is stored on the stack.

Comment: @DavidPeterson: Since activations of asynchronous calls *do not logically form a stack*, we do not use the stack to store continuations of async workflows -- or, rather, we use it less. Getting your head around continuations is tricky, but once you do, many facts about programming become much more clear.

Comment: @EricLippert - "normal return ... information stored on the stack". A big exception to this is legacy code convention for IBM mainframes, which uses a caller provided save area (pointed to by R13, sometimes allocated from the equivalent of a heap). Most financial institutions are still using this legacy code (a combination of Cobol and assembly), since it's not worth the risk or time it would take to convert this huge legacy code base. Reentrant code can use a "linkage stack", but it still involves allocating (and later freeing) save areas from the heap, as opposed to an actual stack.

Comment: @EricLippert - "suppose you had to remove the left-hand recursion" ... . This seems to be similar to limiting quicksort's stack space complexity to O(log(n)) by recursing only on the smaller partition, and looping back to handle the larger partition. It limits stack space, but worst case time complexity is still O(n^2), unless other methods (like choice of pivot) are involved.

Comment: @rcgldr: That's a good point, but I had a different motivation. I try to ask interview questions about problems that the candidate is likely to encounter because I encountered them previously. Consider the problem of running a compiler pass on the parse tree for `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1... + 1` The parse tree will be extremely left-heavy, so if you can remove just the left-hand recursion, you can make it less likely that the compiler will run out of stack space. Machine-generated code often generates long string concatenations or other additions.

Answer (score 7):

As other answers state, your iterative algorithm outperforms your recursive algorithm because the former remembers previous intermediate results (or at least one such result) while the latter doesn’t. Of course, one can write recursive algorithms that remember previous results.

For Fibonacci numbers that’s simple enough since you only need to remember one such result. Using the tuple unpacking syntax of C++17 for sake of readability:

```
#include <utility>

namespace mynamespace {

namespace detail {

std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>
fibonacci_impl(unsigned long long n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return { n, 0 };

    auto [fib1, fib2] = fibonacci_impl(n - 1);
    return { fib1 + fib2, fib1 };
}

} // end namespace detail

unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long n)
{
    return detail::fibonacci_impl(n).first;
}

} // end namespace mynamespace
```

`detail::fibonacci_impl` returns the result of `fibonacci(n)` *and* `fibonacci(n-1)` (as a `pair`) for reuse by the caller. A sufficiently smart compiler can optimize away the overhead of pair packing and unpacking to leave the function call overhead (see [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YrNRwr)) as the only disadvantage of the recursive algorithm over its iterative counterpart.

### Addendum: Namespaces

I enclosed the function declarations into their own namespace `mynamespace` and a sub-namespace `mynamespace::detail`.

If your program is more than trivial you should place your declarations (functions, classes or otherwise) into a separate namespace. For declarations that are meant to be used outside of your own program (e. g. a programming library) it’s highly recommended to do so to avoid name shadowing issues and confusion in general.

If your library declares stuff that is only meant to be used from inside this library, it’s customary to place it inside a sub-namespace whose name indicates its intended nature. Examples that I encountered for such sub-namespace names include: `detail`, `internal`, `implementation` or, shorter, `impl`.

Comment: Don't define names starting with two underscores.

Comment: A single underscore is not as bad as two of them, but still unusual. I don't remember the exact rules for the single underscore, but some of these names are still reserved.

Comment: Why are you putting underscores at the start of your function's name?

Comment: @RolandIllig: Acknowledged and fixed. I read up on C++ naming styles which recommend (anonymous) sub-namespaces for declarations relating to implementation details.

Comment: @theonlygusti: see above

Comment: Note in C defining a global identifier with a leading underscore is undefined (C11, §7.1.3): *"All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."* & *"No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
context in which it is reserved [...] or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined."*

Answer (score 6):

Neither nor!

David Foerster's __fibonacci_impl has a matrix representation, where the matrix can be brought into a diagonal shape, evaluating to a difference of two exponential functions, where the absolute value of the latter one is less than one and so may be replaced by a rounding operator.

[image: Recursion and iteration free evaluation of Fibonacci numbers]

```
 const double sqr5 = sqrt(5);
 const double phi = 0.5 * (sqr5+1);

 double Fn = floor( pow(phi,n) / sqr5 + 0.5); // n<=70
```

Comment: This fails starting at Fib(71).

Comment: @MonicaPolk it just has accuracy limitations due to numerical errors of double. Integer `int64` based slower approach will hit integeroverflow around Fib(92) thus failing miserably and not just being inaccurate.

Comment: @ALX23z - for unsigned 64 bit integers, the limit is Fib(93).

Comment: I just hope this is meant as a joke as this answers almost none of OP's questions and totally misses the point.

Comment: @ALX23z: Then by your own analysis the integer version is superior in an apple-to-apples comparison. Explain how the failure of this method starting at Fib(71) is less miserable than the failure of the integer iteration at Fib(93)?

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk providing accurate answer within 1e-14 relative accuracy is a success in most situations. Getting a completely different unrelated number is typically considered a failure. Is it so hard?

Comment: @ALX23z: The problem is to find the fibonacci number, not an *estimate* of the fibonacii number. 1e-14 relative accuracy represents a total and complete failure in this case. The method you're defending gets an incorrect, completely unrelated number. The integer iteration technique gets the exact correct answer. Do you not understand that a wrong answer is useless?

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk who said that the task is to find fibonacci number exactly? There is function `sin` and `sin(pi)` is not 0 as it should be. Do you say that all `sin` also a total failure? Perhaps, also claim that PI in incorrectly represented?

Comment: @ALX23z: There is no possibly way to read the original question and conclude that an approximation to Fib(n) is acceptable. It's either equal to Fib(n) or it's not and it's useless.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Thank you for your comment. I added a precondition according to limits of standard doubles.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk exactly there is no exact question, only a vague one: how to compute fibinacchi numbers and what is the fastest way. It lacks necessary context what answer is perfectly correct - only what kind of answers are reasonable. Honestly, you have a severe lack of communication skills or common sense to make any form of judgement of what other people say.

Answer (score 5):

In the recursive version of the code you don't need the function prototype `unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long n);`.

As you mentioned you shouldn't have the `using namespace std;` statement in the code.

We can't answer

> Why do most people (on the internet) recommend using recursion because it's simpler and easier to write the program?(well logically I thought that we should write it in a way that is fast and simple)

Because it is an opinion.

In the iterative version you should also have the `fibonacci(unsigned long long n)` function to make `main()` simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your help..and also let's say that if we don't include using namespace std in our code then for every cout we should say std::cout...and so on and so forth for other elements....otherwise we get an error...

Comment: @DavidPeterson Yes, and `std::cout` is clearer than `cout` because the latter can mean either `std::cout` or `my::obscure::library::cout` (which overloads the `<<` operator to print the values in the form of nasal demons), depending on context and ADL, so code readers have to stop and think for a moment.  This problem is not so evident with `cout`, but consider `data`, `arg`, `visit`, etc., none of which I can immediately realize is actually a name from the standard library. `using namespace std;` also pollutes the global namespace with tons of common identifiers, causing name clashes.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a better way than these two methods?And are these methods complex?

There are better methods, and although not that complex, few people would be able to develop such methods (such as Lucas sequence relations) on their own without relying on some reference.

For the recursive version shown in the question, the number of instances (calls) made to fibonacci(n) will be 2 * fibonacci(n+1) - 1.

As for better methods, Fibonacci(n) can be implemented in O(log(*n*)) time by raising a 2 x 2 matrix =  {{1,1},{1,0}} to a power using exponentiation by repeated squaring, but this takes 12 variables. This can be reduced to 5 variables using a method based on Lucas sequence relations.

Example code; *c* and *d* are used for the repeated squaring, while *a* and *b* are the cumulative results and end up as a = fib(n+1), b = fib(n).

Note: older compilers may be missing `<inttypes.h>` or `<stdint.h>`. If `<inttypes.h>` is not present (Visual Studio 2010), use compiler specific format string for `uint64_t`. If `<stdint.h>` is not present (Visual Studio 2005), use `typedef ... uint64_t` (usually `unsigned long long`) and the appropriate format string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t fib(uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t a, b, c, d;
    a = d = 1;
    b = c = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (n & 1) {
            uint64_t ad = a*d;
            a = ad + a*c + b*d;
            b = ad + b*c;
        }
        n >>= 1;
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        {
            uint64_t dd = d*d;
            d = dd + 2 * d*c;
            c = dd + c*c;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t n;
    for (n = 0; n <= 93; n++)
        printf("%20" PRIu64 " %20" PRIu64 "\n", n, fib(n));
    return 0;
}
```

---

The code is based on Lucas sequence relations for Fibonacci numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Other_relations

Specifically these equations:

```
F(m)   = F(m-1) + F(m-2)
F(m+n) = F(m+1) F(n) + F(m) F(n-1)
F(2n)  = F(n) L(n) = F(n) (F(n+1) + F(n-1))
       = F(n)((F(n) + F(n-1)) + F(n-1))
       = F(n) F(n) + 2 F(n) F(n-1)
```

Initial state:

```
a = F(1) = 1
b = F(0) = 0
c = F(0) = 0
d = F(1) = 1
```

n is treated as the sum of powers of 2: 2^a + 2^b + ... 
for each iteration *i* (starting from 0), let p = 2^i, then

```
c = F(p-1)
d = F(p)
```

To advance to the next iteration, c and d are advanced to F(next power of 2):

```
d' = F(2p) = F(p) F(p+1) + F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p)(F(p) + F(p-1)) + F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p) F(p) + F(p) F(p-1) + F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p) F(p) + 2 F(p) F(p-1)
   = d d + 2 c d

c' = F(2p-1) = F(p+p-1) = F(p+1) F(p-1) + F(p) F(p-2)
   = (F(p) + F(p-1)) F(p-1) + F(p) (F(p) - F(p-1))
   = F(p) F(p-1) + F(p-1) F(p-1) + F(p) F(p) - F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p) F(p) + F(p-1) F(p-1)
   = d d + c c
```

During the calculation of a and b, let *m* = current cumulative sum of bits of n:

```
b = F(m)
a = F(m+1)
```

To update a and b for 1 bits in n corresponding to *p* = current power of 2:

```
a' = F(m+1+p) = F(m+2) F(p) + F(m+1) F(p-1)
   = (F(m+1)+F(m)) F(p) + F(m+1) F(p-1)
   = F(m+1) F(p) + F(m) F(p) + F(m) F(p-1)
   = a d + b d + b c

b' = F(m+p) = F(m+1) F(p) + F(m) F(p-1)
   = a d + b c
```

---

Note that if b' is the max value for uint64_t, a' will overflow, but it's not an issue. However, the algorithm can be modified so that when completed, a = fib(n-1):

```
a = fib(-1) = 1
b = fib(0)  = 0

a = fib(m-1)
b = fib(m)

b' = fib(m+p)
   = fib(m+1)fib(p) + fib(m)fib(p-1)
   = (fib(m) + fib(m-1))fib(p) + fib(m)fib(p-1)
   = fib(m)fib(p) + fib(m-1)fib(p) + fib(m)fib(p-1)
   = bd           + ad             + bc

a' = fib(m-1+p)
   = fib(m)fib(p) + fib(m-1)fib(p-1)
   = bd           + ac

uint64_t fib(uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t a, b, c, d;
    a = d = 1;
    b = c = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (n & 1) {
            uint64_t bd = b*d;
            b = bd + a*d + b*c;
            a = bd + a*c;
        }
        n >>= 1;
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        {
            uint64_t dd = d*d;
            d = dd + 2*d*c;
            c = dd + c*c;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The `#define` makes this program needlessly complicated. Plus the bad variable names. And `main` is missing the return type. We are not in the 1980s anymore.

Comment: @RolandIllig - The variable names are the same as those used in other examples of Lucas sequence methods, with the variation that `c` and `d` are sometimes named `p` and `q`. I don't how the int on main got lost, but it is fixed now. I've been having issues trying to find current examples of this code that clearly state it's a variation of Lucas sequence. I'll update my answer with link(s) if/when I find them. The defines are probably a legacy issue in case a compiler doesn't optimize the two products to a single variable (register). This is an old algorithm.

Comment: @RolandIllig - I found a variation of the method using a, b, p, q [here](https://github.com/zed/txfib/blob/41ea022cc8cffc1d4b63996d313e644b494be7dd/fibonacci.py#L165), but no reference to Lucas sequence.

Comment: @RolandIllig - I haven't been able to find a link for how this code works, so I updated my answer with my own explanation, based on Lucas sequence relations.

Comment: @RolandIllig - the defines are gone, replaced by block local variables. Toby Speight updated the printf to use inttypes.h. (Note VS2010 doesn't have inttypes.h, and VS2005 doesn't have stdint.h, which I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing details. It would be good if you referred to VS2010 and VS2005 directly in your answer instead of this comment. When you said "older compilers" I had thought about the 1990s. The words "old" and "new" should not be used in text that is supposed to stay up-to-date for several years.

Comment: @RolandIllig - fixed now. I also added an alternate version where at completion a = fib(n-1), while b = fib(n) (same as before). I could just switch the explanation and code to the alternate version to keep the answer simple, but after doing a web search, I've found examples of both methods (a = fib(n+1), a = fib(n-1)).

Comment: FYI, in my opinion, the clearest version of the fibonacci "doubling" rules which lead to an O(log(n))-multiplies algorithm is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368738/552). By defining things in terms of the special `mult` operator, the resulting code seems much simpler and cleaner. I'm fairly certain it is equivalent to your code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk - the code is similar. Note that the python code would need to be modified to handle F(0): such as power((1,0),0) == (0,1), but I don't know how to do this generically. The python example is calculating a "power" of {F(1),F(0)}, while my code separates this into an initial state {F(m±1), F(m)}, and then "advances" the initial state by a power of {F(0), F(1)}. By switching from uint64_t to int64_t, the initial state can use negative values for m, since the "advancing" involves calculating F(m+p).

Comment: Actually you use the symmetry of [1,1;1,0]^n = [F_{n+1},F_n;F_n;F_{n-1}] represented by  pair (F_n,F_{n-1}) .

Comment: @SamGinrich - the matrix based method involves 12 variables, the Lucas sequence based method involves 5 variables.

Comment: @rclgdr This is correct for common matrix products, where our matrix has symmetry and dependency by the recursive definition, so that it is sufficient to evaluate the right part of the power matrix, leading exactly to the same algorithm as your approach with Lucas numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating Asymptotic Complexity e.g. with gmp library, shows that rcgldr's algorithm, implementing efficient matrix powers with O(log(n)) mutlipications, has best performance among presented algorithms.

Below compared for n in range 0 .... 647028207

1. Straight Iteration, n steps, takes *O(n^1.60)* time.
2. "Golden Ratio", i.e. above called the "Binet's Formula" due to floating arithmetics takes *O(n^1.25)* time
3. rcgldr's algorithm with *O(n^1.029)* time.

The diagram shows evaluation time for *Fn* in seconds over *n*, both axis logarithmic with base 10, 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

By using that iterative solution, you are indirectly using Dynamic Programming (DP)

**Answer for question number 1:**

Recursion *might* be faster in some cases.

For example, let's say you have a 2d road of size `n * m`. There are blockages in the road, so you can't pass through them.

The objective is to check if there exists *any path* from the top-left corner to the bottom-right (You can only move right or down).

The recursive solution would win as the iterative solution will take `O(N * M)` in the best and the worst case, but the recursive solution will take `O(N + M)` for the best case and `O(N * M)` for the worst case.

An iterative [solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-possible-path-2d-matrix) with a detailed explanation is given here, but I can't find any sources for a recursive solution.

**Answer for question number 2:**

The recursive solution of yours is much slower than the iterative one because you are not using [memoization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overlapping-subproblems-property-in-dynamic-programming-dp-1).

Memoization is not that hard to understand.

Please do try visiting this link: https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-explain-dynamic-programming-to-a-4-year-old

Comment: I don't understand why two people down-voted my answer. Would someone please explain why so that I won't repeat the same mistake in the future? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I fail to see how you answer the questions (why is recursion usually recommended for calculating the Fibonacci sequence? What are possible alternatives to these 2 approach?), it doesn't comment on the code itself, and uses pictures to display text, which is bad form since it cannot be searched and used as a reference in the future. The first 2 points make your answer look like an ad for dynamic programming rather than a code review, and you should use blockquotes and links to the sources for the 3rd point.

Comment: A giant purple rectangle is just hideous, and when scrolling down the page just screams "ADVERTISEMENT!" which causes me to just skip way further down fast and get that thing off my screen.  There is absolutely **NO reason** to have that here.  If you're going to have a quote, use text to do it.  Although that bit seems completely irrelevant to the requested code review (IMHO).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  Nice point! I've changed that

Comment: @gazoh You are right. I thought the OP asked for recursion in general and not specifically for Fibonacci. I am quite sorry. I will edit my answer as soon as possible!

Answer (score 3):

While this question already has many answers, one of which is accepted, I would like to point out that the (naïve) recursive solution presented by OP has a much worse complexity than the iterative version. However, it is perfectly possible to split up the problem into a main function to be called by the user, and an internal helper function doing the work recursively. The below has the same complexity as the OP's iterative solution (and will, in fact, be compiled into an iterative solution by a good compiler), and essentially consists of two one-liners:

```
unsigned long long
fibonacci_internal(unsigned long long n,
                   unsigned long long t1,
                   unsigned long long t2) {
    return (n == 0) ? t1 : fibonacci_internal(n - 1, t2, t2 + t1);
}

unsigned long long fibonacci(unsigned long long n) {
    return fibonacci_internal(n, 0, 1);
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed typos in code.

**EDIT 2:** The reason a sufficiently smart compiler can transform the above into an iterative solution (essentially a loop that uses no extra stack frames) is that the recursive call occurs at the end of a logical branch before returning, with no other operation between the recursive call and the return. This is called *tail recursion*. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923 for more information. The OP's original function has an addition between the recursive call and the return, therefore it is not tail-recursive, the recursive call must use extra stack frames, and the compiler cannot turn it into an iterative solution.

Answer (score 2):

The debate around recursive vs iterative code is endless. Some say that recursive code is more "compact" and simpler to understand.. In both cases (recursion or iteration) there will be some 'load' on the system when the value of n i.e. fib(n) grows large.Thus fib(5) will be calculated instantly but fib(40) will show up after a slight delay. Of course your data type must also be large enough to hold the result.In C I think unsigned long long int on a 64-bit system is the largest that you can get.Beyond that you might want to try to hold the intermediate results in an array.Then the only constraint will be memory.

Answer (score 1):

The equation given by Binet:

fib[n] = (phi^n - (-phi)^(-n)) / sqrt(5) where phi=(1+sqrt(5))/2

will give an accurate answer (unlike the answer above of fib [n] = phi^n / sqrt(5) + 1/2), which breaks down at values of n greater than 70).

Since you can calculate it directly, iteration and recursion are unnecessary.

Comment: 1. Please cite correctly: "[phi^n / sqrt(5) + 1/2]" comes with Gaussian brackets!
2. It is an accurate simplification of your "Binet"-formula, if you follow the math above, valid for all natural numbers, including zero.
3. Inaccurate is the C++-double-power function for larger exponents. The Binet-formula has same dependency and limits in C++ runtime with IEEE doubles.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding, Sam, about the Gaussian brackets. I see you are right about the simplification, due to taking the integer part, since the first part of Binet's Formula, i.e. phi^n/sqrt(5), alternates just above and just under the integer result that is adjusted to by the second part, i.e. -(-phi)^(-n)/sqrt(5). In other words, my comment was unnecessary, so I humbly withdraw. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally tribute to

### When should we use recursion?

In view of formal verification of an algorithm you would write an *invariant*, which is a mathematical model of your algorithm, valid for any variables and arguments, which you prove then. When your result is anyway defined as recursion, as we have it for Fibonacci or Factorial series, proof may be performed by complete induction, where the induction step is trivially the recursive definition.

Investigating the asymptotic complexity, i.e. with large numbers, overhead for instantiating a function many times does not carry.

Though, the recursion depth is crucial as in runtime environments like C++. You must not have a StackOverflow; a recursion depth of O(n) as in the initial example is not acceptable!

So whenever you can control the asymptotic recursion depth and runtime is for the most part in evaluation of your intermediary results, a recursive algorithm is suggested.

Following is an algorithm with digit-wise evaluation of Fibonacci numbers, using two integer series derived from the relationship of Binet's Formula and Hyperbolic Functions; Complexity and recursion depth is O(log(n)).

[image]

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long long N;

static void FibRec(int n, N& S, N&C)
{
    if (n >= 1)
    {
        N S1, C1;
        FibRec(n >> 1, S1, C1);
        if ((n >> 1) & 1)
        {
            C = (5 * C1 * C1 + S1 * S1) >> 1;
        }
        else
        {
            C = (C1 * C1 + 5 * S1 * S1) >> 1;
        }
        S= C1 * S1;
        if (n & 1)
        {
            N Cn0 = C;
            C = (C + S) >> 1;
            S= (5 * S+ Cn0) >> 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        S = 0;
        C = 2;
    }
}


N fibonacci(int n)
{
    N S, C;
    FibRec(n, S,C);
    return (n & 1) ? C : S;
}


int main()
{
    for (int n = 0; n<=93; n++)
    {
        std::cout << "Fib[" << n << "] = " << fibonacci(n) << std::endl;
    }
}
```